# In reshape function of Numpy, what is the significance of giving three parameters, where the first one is -1?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
newarr = arr.reshape(-1,3,2)
newarr
```

Above is the code I did. Here is the output:

```
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]]])
```

But I cannot understand what the -1 did. -1 alone is supposed to flatten the array, i.e, converting a multidimensional array to single dimensional array. When -1 was used with 2,3 , what has happened to the output?

Comment: What is the resulting `shape`?  Try several cases and deduce for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the numpy.reshape [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) say:

> One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

That is, -1 means "please figure this shape dimension out". It will be computed so that the number of elements remains the same as in the original array.

In your example, since the rest of your shape dimensions are 2 and 3, that already covers all 6 elements. Thus, the inferred (first) shape dimension must be 1, and the shape of resulting array is (1, 2, 3).

Another example:

```
arr = np.arange(27)  # 1-dim array of 27 elements
newarr = arr.reshape(-1,3,3)
```

In this case, the resulting `newarr.shape` will be (3,3,3), so you get 27 elements.

Comment: The resulting shape will be *1*, 2, 3, not 0, 2, 3.

Comment: @user3483203 Thanks. Getting too tired :)